# Ender 3 X-axis layer shifting

Tags: creality-ender-3

I've been having a problem lately with some minor layer shifting with my Ender 3. It just started recently and I've made no changes to the printer since it was working fine. The layer shifting is always on the X-axis and it's not a large amount. Just enough to render my prints useless. The shift can happen in either direction on the X-axis. See attached photo.

Things I've tried:

1. Retensioning the belts
2. Printing at slower speeds
3. Checking all bed connections to make sure the bed is solid
4. Reducing the jerk setting
5. Activating Z-hop
6. Reducing acceleration
7. Increased retraction.

The problem occurs on multiple STL files that used to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with random layer shifts along the X axis]

Comment: Did you reslize the model?

Comment: In the case of the model I show in the photo, I resized the top to stretch it a little taller. In other models that are showing the same layer shifting, I did not resize,

Comment: not resize, RE-sliced. As in, did you print old G-code or freshly sliced one?

Comment: I've run prints with gcode files that predate this problem and the same shifting occurs. I even went so far as to uninstall Cura 4.5 and reinstall 4.1 and still get the layer shifts

Comment: I know this is old, but from the picture these are very clearly not "layer shifts". There is no accumulation of error, just layer-dependent (direction-dependent?) minor displacement, which is **always** just lack of rigidity in some part of the motion/positioning system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK I found the answer. I removed the extruder cover and found that the 2 screws attaching the extruder assembly were loose. A very simple fix to a very irritating problem.